# Access uploaded image in NodeJS in AngularJS via ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload framework to save images. I am facing an issue. I am successfully able to upload the image into an image folder and image is being saved like `CPqc3h_zWwr_5n9xOzTBybz4.png`. I am trying to access this image in frontend by `http://localhost:5040/images/CPqc3h_zWwr_5n9xOzTBybz4.png` but it is giving me 404. 
I also tried to do fs.readFile(); and send the binary data into frontend but I don't know how to convert it back into Image. I would like to also to know the best practice MEAN Stack developers take around the world to solve this issue.

Comment: It is a backend nodejs MEAN.js question. Tag your question with mean.js too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the absolute path in the image reference, use a relative path instead

Change this
`http://localhost:5040/images/CPqc3h_zWwr_5n9xOzTBybz4.png`

And In your controller or service or factory reference the image like

$scope.var.imageURL = './images/CPqc3h_zWwr_5n9xOzTBybz4.png'`

And render it to the client like
`<img ng-src={{var.imageURL}}`

Comment: The only problem is ... when ng-file-upload saves file it just saves the name of file. So instead of opening the file. It downloads it. Because there is no extension to it. So how do I attach an extension, or ensure that extension of file comes along with it?

Comment: IMO and perhaps I'm misunderstanding your setup, is that you use ng-file-upload, and then display the image once its uploaded using ng-repeat

Comment: yes.. This is what I want. Ng-repeat is optional. But I want to immediately show the image and it should persist on reload.